# How do I get deployed model from `ListEndpointsRequest`?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-vertex-ai

My code is:

```
   client = aiplatform_v1.EndpointServiceClient(client_options=options)
    parent = client.common_location_path(project=project_id, location=location)
    

    # Initialize request argument(s)
    request = aiplatform_v1.ListEndpointsRequest(
        parent=parent
    )

    # Make the request
    endpoints_pager = client.list_endpoints(request=request)
    for endpoint in endpoints_pager.pages:
        latest_endpoint=endpoint
        print(endpoint.deployed_models.id)
```

If I print `endpoint` I see `{...deployed_models { id: ...}}`
`endpoint.deployed_models.id)` doesn't work so how do I get the deployed model id?

Comment: `deployed_models` is a Sequence (see [`Endpoint`](https://cloud.google.com/python/docs/reference/aiplatform/latest/google.cloud.aiplatform_v1.types.Endpoint)) so you need to iterate over it (`for deployed_model in endpoint.deployed_models`) to enumerate each `id`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @DazWilkin mentioned in the comments, you need to iterate through `deployed_models` to get the `id` per model. Applying this, your code should look like this:

IMPORTANT NOTE FOR FUTURE READERS: When creating `client` it is needed to define the `api_endpoint` in `client_options`. If not not defined you will encounter a **google.api_core.exceptions.MethodNotImplemented: 501 Received http2 header with status: 404** error.

```py
from google.cloud import aiplatform_v1

def sample_list_endpoints():

    project_id = "your-project-id"
    location = "us-central1"

    client = aiplatform_v1.EndpointServiceClient(client_options={"api_endpoint":"us-central1-aiplatform.googleapis.com"})

    parent = client.common_location_path(project=project_id, location=location)
    # Initialize request argument(s)
    request = aiplatform_v1.ListEndpointsRequest(
        parent=parent,
    )

    # Make the request
    page_result = client.list_endpoints(request=request)

    # Handle the response
    for response in page_result:
        for model in response.deployed_models:
            print(model.id)

sample_list_endpoints()
```